# I can not install pyfribidi package on python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem installing the pyfribidi package on Python. When installing, it gives an error. I will send the picture. Also, I have installed all the prerequisites of the visual studio build tool. Thanks to dear Noah and all friend in stackoverflow ,sorry my bad english

pic error: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6MsU.jpg)

text error :
C:\Windows\system32>pip install pyfribidi
Collecting pyfribidi
Using cached pyfribidi-0.12 .0.zip (788 kB)
Installing build dependencies done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\program files\python 37\lib\site-packages (from pyfribidi) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyfribidi
Building wheel for pyfribidi (pyproject.toml)
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
-> 3 1ines of output]
done
x Building wheel for pyfribidi (pyproject. toml) did not run successfully .
exit code: 1
operable program or bat ch file.
"sh is not recognized as an internal or external command,
error
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools" : https://visualstudio . microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
fend of output
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyfribidi
Failed to build pyfribidi
C:\Windows\system32>
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyfribidi, which is required to install pyproject.toml - based projects

Comment: Please provide the text of the error message instead of a screenshot. This will help others to copy/paste some of the terms in the error message if required. This also helps visually impaired people as they can use a text-to-speech tool to understand your question better.

Comment: yes brother sure